# I'm recently reading opencv source code. Is there some better ways to find class definitions in opencv library?

Tags: c++, opencv

For example, I find a declaration of UMat class in mat.hpp, but how do I find the definition of UMat? There is no mat.cpp over there. And I checked almost all cpp files related on matrix, still cannot target it. I swear I tried my best. Anyone has some suggestions that help me find definitions efficiently? By the way, I didn't download the source code but read it on github. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV maintain a site for documentation. It's not perfect, but it might help; found [here.](https://docs.opencv.org/master/index.html) If you just need information on what the classes do I'd look here.

If you do need to stare at the internal gubbins of their classes, there is a standard file hierarchy they use in their github repo.

For a given module (in the case of Umat, the Core Module) there will be a folder with several subfolders. The subfolder `/include/opencv2` will have the class declarations, the subfolder `\src` will have the definitions. In the case of Umat the definition is located [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/umatrix.cpp) as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. By the way, if the maintainers add notes in header files and tell explicitly where are the definitions, that could be way better.

Comment: Good answer. I personally think the docs are pretty good. And if you need more help, the [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html) are really good.